# SQL Union with Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

This is a continuation of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280207/sql-partial-full-outer-join). My two tables look like this:

```
Table1
Name    Id      Amount 
Name1   1       99
Name1   1       30
Name1   9       120.2
Name2   21      348
Name2   21      21
Name3   41      99
Name6   20      23

Table2
Name    Id      Return Amount 
Name1   1       99
Name1   1       30
Name1   9       120.2
Name2   21      348
Name2   21      21
Name3   41      99
Name4   19      923.2
Name5   23      12
```

I need a resultant table that looks like this:

```
Name    Id      Amounts    Returns
Name1   1       2          2
Name1   9       1          2
Name2   21      2          1
Name3   41      1          1
Name4   1       0          1
Name5   23      0          1
Name6   20      1          0
```

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT
    [Name],
    [Id],
    ISNULL(count([Amount]), 0) as 'Amounts'
FROM table1 AS A
GROUP BY [Name], [Id]
UNION (
            SELECT
                [Name],
                [Id],
                ISNULL(count([Return Amount]), 0) as 'Returns'
            FROM 
                table2 AS B
            GROUP BY [Name], [Id]
)
```

But that gives me:

```
Name    Id      Amounts
Name1   1       4
Name1   9       3
Name2   21      3
Name3   41      2
Name4   1       1
Name5   23      1
Name6   20      1
```

I know I need to put the `Return Amount` in the SELECT statement but I'm not sure how to do that, everything I've tried results in a syntax error because of that union.

What's the right way of going about this?

Update 1:
Tried

```
SELECT
    A.[Name],
    A.[Id],
    count(A.[Amount]),
    count(B.[Return])
FROM (
    SELECT
        [Name],
        [Id],
        count([Amount]) as 'Amounts'
    FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT 
            [Name],
            [Id],
            count([Return]) as 'Returns'
    FROM table2
) AS A
LEFT JOIN table2 as B on A.[Id] = B.[Id]
GROUP BY A.[Name], A.[Id]
```

But I get the error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'table1.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Amount'.
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this? You could use that answer to work on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280207/sql-partial-full-outer-join

Comment: Returns for 9  shoud be 1 not 2 ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Partial Full Outer Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280207/sql-partial-full-outer-join)

Comment: @manderson it's not because the difference here is that there are rows in `table2` with id's that don't match anything from `table1` but I still want them to show up in the resultant table.

Comment: Returns count for Name1 ID 9 seems incorrect given sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both table using UNION and split amounts and returns in two columns:

```
select name, id,  count(Amount) AS Amounts, count("Return Amount") AS returns
from ( 
   select name, id, Amount, NULL as "Return Amount" 
   from table1
   union all
   select name, id, NULL, "Return Amount" 
   from table2
)  t1
group by name, id
```

Comment: @Richard: Well, that's how you named the column: `Return Amount`

Comment: PERFECT, THIS WORKED!

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your date  seems you need a a left join and group by

```
select a.name, a.id,  count(a.Amount) Amountes, count(b.Returns)
from ( 
   select name, id, Amount
   from table1
   union 
   select name, id, `Return Amount` 
   from table2
)  t1 as a 
left join Table2 as b on a.id = b.id
group by a.name, a.id
```

Comment: this doesn't give me what I want because `name4` and `name5` don't appear in the resultant table since their id's don't match with anything in table`. I essentially need to union the two tables then combine wherever there's duplicate `id` numbers

Comment: I had to make an edit but this still doesn't work. Update in the post

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the counts before the join so we don't have a problem with artificial count inflation due to carndality between the tables.  I also don't see why a union is necessary as a full outer join seems like it would work...

We have to use coalesce as we don't know if name or ID exists in both tables such as Name 6 and name 5

```
SELECT Coalesce(T1.Name, T2.Name) as Name
     , Coalesce(T1.ID, T2.ID) as ID
     , Coalesce(T1.Amount,0) as Amount
     , coalesce(T2.Returns,0) as Returns
FROM (SELECT Name, ID, count(1) as Amount from table1 GROUP BY name, ID) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT Name, ID, count(1) as Returns from table2 GROUP BY name, ID) T2
 on T1.Name = T2.Name
and T1.ID = T2.ID
```